# Tree combinations and partitioning

Tags: c#, tree

I have a (non-binary) tree containing records with strings.

I would like to make arrays of the records (or pointers to the records) containing the data as follows...

I made this illustrated sample:

```
       ABCDEFGHIJKL
      /     |      \
   ABC      DE      FGHIJKL
  /   \            /   |   \
AB     C        FGH   IJK   L
                      / \
                     I  JK
```

The result should be:
(7 arrays containing the records with this data)

1. ABCDEFGHIJKL
2. ABC, DE, FGHIJKL
3. ABC, DE, FGH, I, JK, L
4. ABC, DE, FGH, IJK, L
5. AB, C, DE, FGHIJKL
6. AB, C, DE, FGH, I, JK, L
7. AB, C, DE, FGH, IJK, L

Some notes:

- I don't care about the order of the (1-7) results as long as I get them all.
- I'm working with C#
- In this sample there are 4 levels with 7 paths, but in real life it can be any number of levels.
- The pattern here is creating `"ABCDEFGHIJKL"` from all my combinations left to right.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Is there a particular pattern to the data you're trying to extract? Also, your array #3 and #5 are identical.

Comment: Do you have a tree or do you want to make one? And I have trouble detecting the logic in these 9 samples, can you put it into words?

Comment: Hi! i already have a tree. and Jim you are right... 3 and 5 are identical it is my mistake... as long as you can see the pattern of creating the "ABCDEFGHIJKL" from all of it parts, left to right.

Comment: I can make out 4 levels and 7 paths but not your 9 results. Please re-check, correct and describe what you want.

Comment: i has 2 duplicates... so i removed it... it is correct now. sorry!

Comment: yes Henk, this is exactly what i want. i had my mistakes and i corrected it. sorry again. there are 7 paths here... is this a generic solution to fit more or less than 4 levels?? because this is just a sample... in real life i may have a different number of levels

Comment: It still makes no sense. Why isn't "ABCDEFGHIJK, ABC, AB" not in the results? Again: try to describe the rules.

Comment: Good to see you again Henk. the logic is to make "ABCDEFGHIJKL" from all of my combinations left to right. i can clearly see it.

Comment: left node always precede right node with the constrained of making the following "ABCDEFGHIJKL" combination by this order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is simple. Have a list with only the root node, then replace it by its children. Then replace every node in that list recursively and add that list to the result collection on every replace operation.

That way we will get repeating results in some branches, so we'll pass the result collection through the recursion and check if current nodes list is already there. If it is, then its derived lists too, so just return.

Say we have a class `Tree` with nodes of class `Node` (each node has `Children`). Tree root is `Root`. Then you can implement your function like this (inside the `Tree` class):

```
public List<List<Node>> GetLevels() {
    List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
    nodes.Add(Root);
    List<List<Node>> result = new List<List<Node>>();
    GetLevelsCore(nodes, result);
    return result;
}
void GetLevelsCore(List<Node> nodes, List<List<Node>> result) {
    if(result.Any(list => list.SequenceEqual(nodes))) return;
    result.Add(nodes);

    foreach(Node node in nodes) {
        if(node.Children.Count != 0) {
            List<Node> replacedNodes = new List<Node>(nodes);
            int index = replacedNodes.IndexOf(node);
            replacedNodes.RemoveAt(index);
            replacedNodes.InsertRange(index, node.Children);

            GetLevelsCore(replacedNodes, result);
        }
    }
}
```

The results I got:

```
List<List<Node>> result = tree.GetLevels();
List<string> strings = new List<string>(result.Select(nodes => string.Join(", ", nodes.Select(node => node.Value))));
```

`strings`:

1. "ABCDEFGHIJKL"
2. "ABC, DE, FGHIJKL"
3. "AB, C, DE, FGHIJKL"
4. "AB, C, DE, FGH, IJK, L"
5. "AB, C, DE, FGH, I, JK, L"
6. "ABC, DE, FGH, IJK, L"
7. "ABC, DE, FGH, I, JK, L"

UPD: replaced Contains check with Any(), no need for equality comparers now.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, it does not compile here.... can you somehow send me the source code for this.. .i'will appreciate. mndlee094@yahoo.com

Comment: Sure thing, sent it. May be it's the .Net version, or just the usings.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you - your tree looks (potentially) like this, where a `.` indicates a node with children but no "content" and `AB` indicates a node with text content "AB".

```
                                       .
                                 /     |      \ 
                                .      DE     .
                               /  \        /   |   \
                             AB    C      FGH  .    L
                                              / \
                                             I  JK
```

ie: One root node with 3 child nodes (1 is a leaf containing the text "DE").

I'm assuming that you already have your data structure which will be a tree where each node can have 3 child nodes, one parent and an optional text field. Something like:

```
class Node
{
    // NB: I would not implement the class exactly like this - for illustrative purposes only.
    Node Left;
    Node Mid;
    Node Right;
    string Text;
}
```

What you want to achieve is to traverse the tree and concatenate all the text at or below a particular level?

So something like,

- level 4: I + JK = "IJK"
- level 3: AB + C + FGH + (I + JK) + L = "ABCDFGHIJKL"
- level 2: (AB + C) + DE +(FGH + (I + JK) + L) = "ABCDEFGHIJKL"

To work with trees in this way you'll likely have to use recursion. You'll need to write a [recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) to find the nodes you need, keep track of the depth etc. and perform the text / data operations you want.

A helpful aid to this would be to make each node store it's depth in the tree when inserted, if you have control over it.

For example, a very simple recursive function which just finds you the text of all nodes of a certain level might look something a little like this:

```
//NB: Comes with no warrentee and untested :).
public string TextAtLevel(Node root, int maxLevel, int currentLevel)
{
    currentlevel += 1;

    if(currentLevel == maxLevel)
    {
        // stop the recursion, return text of this node
        return root.Text;
    }
    else
    {
         //Recurse into the child nodes. Left to right, depth first.
         return TextAtLevel(root.Left, maxLevel, currentLevel) + 
                TextAtLevel(root.Mid, maxLevel, currentLevel) + 
                TextAtLevel(root.Right, maxLevel, currentLevel)
    }

}

Node treeRoot = LoadData(); // imagine tree being populated as per diagram.
string textAtLevel4 = TextAtLevel(treeRoot, 4, 0); // returns "IJK"
```

Hopefully this might help you get started.

Comment: Hi Xan, all my nodes containing data. and 3 children for some nodes is just for simplicity... it can be also less or more than that. i'm looking carefully in your answer to find my clues to proceed with it. thanks.